# Parse ini file with brackets

Tags: php, parsing, ini

I have an .ini files which contains brackets `( )` 
As php.net recomend I parse.ini file with parse_ini_file() functio, so let's say my code looks like:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('files/models.ini');
```

then error looks like:

```
Warning: syntax error, unexpected '(' in files/models.ini on line 4 in \index.php on line 48
```

This is text from line 4

```
00name1=100 08/82-11/90 (443/445) Typový sešit [V] [27]
```

Problem is I am getting this file from outsite and I can not change it,

From multiple sites I notice that some words have special meaning in ini file like "null" "true" "no" "yes" but this is not this kind of situation.

So guys can somebody advise me what I am doing wrong or if this is impossible is there any workaround?

Comment: The simplest solution would be that you put quotes around your values in your ini file

Comment: Yea I understand, but unfortunately I can't do it :(

Comment: Does your ini file has any comments in it or [sections] ?

Comment: it does, here s full example 
00name34=A7 Sportback kupé od 07/10 (4G) [V] [S] [3D] [IRE] [12]

Comment: Ummm `parse_ini_file()` is for parsing files that specifically conform to the structure used by **php.ini** not just any random .ini file you happen to use...

Comment: is there any other way you suggest to use then? I am up for anything which let me work with arrays or objects:)

Comment: If you don't know precisely how **models.ini** is structured, you're going to have a bad time of it... unless it conforms to some kind of standard that already exists you'll probably need to write your own parser for it... which may well involve a whole world of Regular Expressions... just because a file happens to have a *.ini* extension doesn't mean whoever wrote it conformed to any particular standard : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/INI_file

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the option `INI_SCANNER_RAW`:

```
$ini = parse_ini_file('files/models.ini', false, INI_SCANNER_RAW);
```

From the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-ini-file.php#refsect1-function.parse-ini-file-parameters):

> If INI_SCANNER_RAW is supplied, then option values will not be parsed.

Result from my test:

```
$ php test.php
array(1) {
  ["foo"]=>
  string(9) "foo (bar)"
  ["00name1"]=>
  string(49) "100 08/82-11/90 (443/445) Typový sešit [V] [27]"
}
```